# javascript innerHTML if classList contains this

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I want to edit a paragraph element -

```
<p id="individualDescription"></p>
```

on my HTML depending on which slide is active on my html. I am using a bootstrap carousel, which passes on the class active to whichever picture is currently showing.

I am currently using the classList.contains to check if the element has the class and the innerHTML to write in the paragraph.

JS:

```
var slideIndex1 = document.querySelector('#firstSlide');
var slideIndex2 = document.querySelector('#secondSlide');
var slideIndex3 = document.querySelector('#thirdSlide');
var slideIndex4 = document.querySelector('#fourthSlide');
var workoutDescription = document.querySelector('#individualDescription');

if (slideIndex1.classList.contains('active')) {
  workoutDescription.innerHTML = 'This is Slide 1';
} else if (slideIndex2.classList.contains('active')) {
  workoutDescription.innerHTML = 'This is Slide 2';
} else if (slideIndex3.classList.contains('active')) {
  workoutDescription.innerHTML = 'This is Slide 3';
} else if (slideIndex4.classList.contains('active')) {
  workoutDescription.innerHTML = 'This is Slide 4';
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" id="firstSlide" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" id="secondSlide"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" id="thirdSlide"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3" id="fourthSlide"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="../Images/IW_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="../Images/IW_2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="../Images/IW_3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="../Images/IW_4.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

This is the code for the slideshow. It works fully so there are no problems here.

I am not sure exactly why the text that I am trying to display is not being displayed - the paragraph element stays empty and nothing is changed.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: `document.querySelector('active').id` is a better way to find which slide is active, can avoid all of your variables this way. You could store the pretty name (ie Slide 1 instead of firstSlide) in a data attribute as well to avoid a chain of if/else or a case statement(s).

Comment: What isn't working about it? Could you include your html as well?

Comment: @cb64 The javascript message is not displayed, instead, the paragraph element stays empty. I have just edited my post to include the html

Comment: I can't find an element with id *individualDiscription* in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap's carousel, It's safe to assume you are using JQUERY. If that is the case, you could find the index of the item with the active class and use a switch.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var msg = "";

switch($(".carousel-item.active").index()){
    case 1: msg = "test1";break;
    case 2: msg = "test2";break;
    case 3: msg = "test3";break;
}
$("#individualDescription").html(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-item active"></div>
<div class="carousel-item"></div>
<div class="carousel-item"></div>

<p id="individualDescription"></p>
```